# Is the unmounting cleanup callback of a component guaranteed to execute before the mounting callback of another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
function A({}) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
   // do stuff  
 
   return () => cleanup_callback_of_A();
  }, [])

  return <div />
}
```

```
function B({}) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
   mounting_callback_of_B();
  }, [])

  return <div />
}
```

If the user navigates from path `/A` to `/B`, is it guaranteed that `cleanup_callback_of_A` will execute before `mounting_callback_of_B`?

`A` is the component rendered under the path `/A`. And `B` is the component rendered under the path `/B`.

Comment: Are you asking about React Router?

Comment: yes, react-router, react-router-dom

Comment: Isn't this trivially testable? It makes sense that when one component is unmounting that its effects' cleanup functions will run prior to it unmounting prior to another component mounting in its place prior to its initial render prior to any of its effects being run.